# Semi Colon Separated Values into a List - AMP Script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to convert semi-colon separated values into a list using AMP Script like the example below:

**Structure in the data extension tab:** 1 Orange ;2 Apples ;3 Peaches ;5 Plums

**Expected Output:**

- 1 Orange
- 2 Apples
- 3 Peaches
- 5 Plums

Comment: Have you checked on this [BuildRowSetFromString](https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromstring/)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the [BuildRowsetFromString](https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromstring/)  function:

```
%%[

set @list = "1 Orange;2 Apples;3 Peaches;5 Plums"

set @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@list,";")
set @rowCount = rowCount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @fruit = field(@row,1)

    ]%%

    <br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%, fruit: %%=v(@fruit)=%%

    %%[

  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```